# user & request.user displaying different objects - Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

Not even sure where to begin here.

Currently running into an issue where users are intermittently loading pages to find themselves "logged in" as other users (Templates rendering with wrong context). The error seems to come down to `request.user` showing the incorrect user while `user` has the correct user context. I currently use `{{request.user}}` in my templates and recognize that I could just switch to `{{user}}` but don't want to look over anything deeper that is going wrong. Any idea what would cause this? I've confirmed this issue is only contained to the site proper templates. The Admin site as well as some AJAX requests I have going to the server all seem to be processing the correct user context.

EX.

[image: UID = 124 while User-UID = 174 in template]

This is from a template render captured while the issue presented itself. UID is the user id from `request.user.pk` while User-UID is from `user.pk`

---

I thought it could be the context processors, but I don't think my ordering is any cause for concern:

```
"django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
"django.template.context_processors.debug",
"django.template.context_processors.request",
"django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
```

I've done my fair share of googling and head-banging so any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you have any caching enabled on your views or templates? This sort of thing can easily happen if you cache stuff globally that is supposed to be user-specific. The fact that it only happens in your templates strongly suggests this is a possibility.

Comment: @solarissmoke I do not but I was able to track down and solve the issue yesterday. It was frankly a silly mistake enabled by some poor design decisions made a while back. I wrote the request data to a dictionary that was then shared globally by all templates due to a mixin used across all views on the site when it really should be flushed after every page-load. Thank you for your help though!